# Connection to NAO Robot from Different Network

Tags: nao-robot

I am working on a project with the NAO robot. Part of this project requires remotely connecting to the NAO robot outside of a shared network.

For example: I am at a friend's house and want to control my robot located in my home. However, I do not know how to get an external IP from NAO and therefore cannot connect to the robot unless I am in my own home.

Is it possible to assign/retrieve an external IP for remote use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. You have different possibilities:

a) Create a [VPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) (Virtual Private Network) between your friend's house and your house. With this solution, you will find your robot in your friend's network.

b) Configure your router to [forward one public port](https://superuser.com/a/284073) of your public IP to your Nao's IP. Now you can send commands to your house's IP. The commands will be forwarded to the robot.

Indeed is the same problem that if you want to get the public IP of your laptop or tablet.

Comment: I ended up solving my problem before you responded, but I did exactly as you suggested in b). However, I did not even think of creating a VPN! Thanks!